# Why is it that a closed unbounded operator can never have a closed domain?

Tags: operator-theory, unbounded-operators

I have seen a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620459/unbounded-linear-operator-in-a-closed-domain)
that tries to answer this.
My question is why in practice closed unbounded operators cannot have a closed domain.
Is it because a closed domain would imply the domain becomes bounded? I need some clarification.

Comment: Yes I’m working with Banach spaces, but not necessarily a symmetric operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at an unbounded linear operator $T:D\subseteq X \rightarrow Y$ with closed graph, where $X$, $Y$ are Banach spaces, the answer is very easy. $D$ has to be a subspace, otherwise the concept of $T$ being linear would not make sense.

If $D$ is closed, it has to be Banach. Remember that $X$ is Banach.

In that case, the closed graph theorem applies which exactly states that $T$ is continuous.

Comment: That clears my confusion. +1